# Linear Algebra: Rotation and base change problem

Tags: linear-algebra

I can't seem to get the correct answer according to my book.

$L$ is a linear map that rotates vectors in $R^3$ then angle $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$ around the line with $\vec{n}=(1,2,2)^T$ as direction vector. The rotation is made counter clockwise seen from the tip of $\vec{n}$. Determine $L$:s matrix $A$ in the standard base.

The chapter is on changing of basis, so it want me to create an orthogonal base $f$ where $\vec{f}_1$ is parallell with $\vec{n}$, crate the rotation matrix $A_f$ in that base, and then through that calculate the matrix $A_e$ in the standard bas.
My solution:\

$\vec{f}_1=\frac{1}{3} \begin{bmatrix} 1\\2\\2 \end{bmatrix}$

$\vec{f}_2$ and $\vec{f}_3$ will lie in the plane orthogonal to $\vec{f}_1$: $x+2y+2z=0$.

If we choose $\vec{f}_2=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\-1\end{bmatrix}\ \Rightarrow \ \vec{f}_3=\vec{f}_1\times \vec{f}_2=\frac{1}{\sqrt{18}}\begin{bmatrix}-4\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}$
$$f=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{3}&0&\frac{-4}{\sqrt{18}}\\ \frac{2}{3}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{18}}\\ \frac{2}{3}&\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{18}}\end{pmatrix}$$

Rotation $\pi/4$ around $\vec{f}_1$ will, in base $f$, have the matrix $$A_f=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}\\0&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{pmatrix}$$

$X_e=fX_f$, where $f$ is the matrix with column vectors the describe the $f$-basis vectors in the standard base, and $X_e,X_f$ are the coordinate matrices for standard basis and $f$-basis respectively.

$A_fX_f=f^{-1}A_efX_f$, where $A_e$ is the rotation matrix in standard basis, and since $f$ is an orthogonal matrix $f^{-1}=f^T$. This leads to
$$A_e=fA_ff^T$$

I used my calculator to get the result which is full of deciamals~
$$A_e\approx \begin{pmatrix}0.740&-0.406&0.536\\0.536&0.837&-0.106\\-0.406&0.366&0.837\end{pmatrix}$$

My book says: $$A_e=\frac{1}{9} \begin{pmatrix}1&-4&8\\8&4&1\\-4&7&4\end{pmatrix}$$

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Your work is correct.  I verified it.  Must be an error in the book.

Comment: Thank you. I can't let go when I don't understand where I'm wrong.